# How to solve this slf4j exception , log method not found

Tags: spring, maven, jakarta-ee, slf4j

I am getting following SLF4J Exception, I Have Tried Removing slf4j Dependencies from pom.xml , still it persist , can anybody help ??

The Exception Thrown is as :
.
.
.

> ```
>  " org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Exception in
>  oracle.acs.assessment.PatchDataExtractionActivator.start() of bundle
>  oracle.acs.mf.PatchDataExtractionBundle.
>          at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:1018)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:260)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:252)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:260)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >         at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >         at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:150)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:291)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.console(FrameworkConsole.java:276)
> >         at com.sun.svc.container.admin.cli.Console.run(Console.java:85)
> >         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
> >         at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:288)
> >         at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:199)
> >         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:412)
> >         at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:350)
> >         at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
> >         at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
> >         at oracle.acs.assessment.util.SpringHelper.initContext(SpringHelper.java:34)
> >         at oracle.acs.assessment.util.SpringHelper.getBean(SpringHelper.java:57)
> >         at oracle.acs.assessment.PatchDataExtractionActivator.start(PatchDataExtractionActivator.java:50)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
> >         at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >         at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
> >         ... 14 more Nested Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> ```
>
> org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
>
> > ```
> >     at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:288)
> >     at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:199)
> >     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:412)
> >     at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:350)
> >     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
> >     at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
> >     at oracle.acs.assessment.util.SpringHelper.initContext(SpringHelper.java:34)
> >     at oracle.acs.assessment.util.SpringHelper.getBean(SpringHelper.java:57)
> >     at oracle.acs.assessment.PatchDataExtractionActivator.start(PatchDataExtractionActivator.java:50)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
> >     at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:260)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:252)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:260)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >     at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:150)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:291)
> >     at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.console(FrameworkConsole.java:276)
> >     at com.sun.svc.container.admin.cli.Console.run(Console.java:85)
> >     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724) Nested Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
> > ```
> >
> > org.slf4j.spi.LocationAwareLogger.log(Lorg/slf4j/Marker;Ljava/lang/String;ILjava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/Throwable;)V
> >             at org.apache.log4j.Category.log(Category.java:288)
> >             at org.apache.commons.logging.impl.Log4JLogger.info(Log4JLogger.java:199)
> >             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.prepareRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:412)
> >             at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:350)
> >             at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
> >             at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:93)
> >             at oracle.acs.assessment.util.SpringHelper.initContext(SpringHelper.java:34)
> >             at oracle.acs.assessment.util.SpringHelper.getBean(SpringHelper.java:57)
> >             at oracle.acs.assessment.PatchDataExtractionActivator.start(PatchDataExtractionActivator.java:50)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl$2.run(BundleContextImpl.java:999)
> >             at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:993)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:974)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.BundleHost.startWorker(BundleHost.java:346)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:260)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.AbstractBundle.start(AbstractBundle.java:252)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandProvider._start(FrameworkCommandProvider.java:260)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> >             at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
> >             at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> >             at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkCommandInterpreter.execute(FrameworkCommandInterpreter.java:150)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.docommand(FrameworkConsole.java:291)
> >             at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.internal.core.FrameworkConsole.console(FrameworkConsole.java:276)
> >             at com.sun.svc.container.admin.cli.Console.run(Console.java:85)
> >             at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:724)

My Pom File is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>oracle.acs.mf</groupId>
        <artifactId>assessment</artifactId>
        <version>all</version>
        <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
    </parent>
    <groupId>oracle.acs.mf</groupId>
    <artifactId>PatchDataExtractionBundle</artifactId>
    <version>${assmnt.version}</version>
    <packaging>bundle</packaging>
    <name>Sun IT Services :: Monitoring Framework :: PatchDataExtractionBundle Bundle</name>
    <description>PatchDataExtractionBundle OSGi bundle project.</description>
    <properties>
        <slf4j.version>1.6.1</slf4j.version>
        <logback.version>1.0.11</logback.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.cs</groupId>
            <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.6</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.mf</groupId>
            <artifactId>MonitoringFrameworkBundle</artifactId>
            <version>3.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
            <!--<scope>provided</scope>-->
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle.acs.platform</groupId>
            <artifactId>MonitoringFrameworkBundle</artifactId>
            <!--<version>all</version>-->
            <version>3.5.999</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.4</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.osgi</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.osgi.core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.karaf.shell</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.apache.karaf.shell.console</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.3</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle.jdbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>ojdbc14</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.0.5.0</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse</groupId>
            <artifactId>osgi</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.0.v20090520</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>${logback.version}</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>oracle.acs.mf</groupId>
            <artifactId>assessment-common</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.10</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.2</version>
            <type>jar</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-bundle-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.7</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <instructions>
                        <Bundle-Name>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-Name>
                        <Bundle-SymbolicName>${project.groupId}.${project.artifactId}</Bundle-SymbolicName>
                        <Bundle-Version>${project.version}</Bundle-Version>
                        <Bundle-Activator>oracle.acs.assessment.PatchDataExtractionActivator</Bundle-Activator>
                        <Embed-Dependency>*;scope=compile|runtime</Embed-Dependency>
                        <!-- include the complete set of transitive dependencies -->
                        <Embed-Transitive>true</Embed-Transitive>
                        <Embed-Directory>META-INF/lib</Embed-Directory>
                        <!-- Custom entries
                        <CONFIG_FILE>/${install.config.dir}/patch_assessment.properties</CONFIG_FILE>-->
                        <Export-Package>
                            oracle.acs.assessment.service.*;oracle.acs.assessment.entity.*;version=${project.version}
                        </Export-Package>
                        <Import-Package>
                            org.osgi.service.http,
                            org.osgi.framework;version="1.3.0",
                            org.eclipse.osgi.framework.console, *;resolution:=optional
                        </Import-Package>
                    </instructions>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
             <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                  <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Comment: The answer depends on what you want to do. Do you want to use slf4j for logging? If so, removing it is quite counterproductive. Apparently one of your dependencies uses apache commons logging, but can't find an implementation of it. So *if* you want to log via slf4j/logback, you have to add the jcl-over-slf4j dependency which you excluded in your pom. It makes sure all jcl-events are routed via slf4j instead.

Comment: yes i want to use slf4j for logging, Since i was getting error that method not found exception , so i surfed the internet and found that the error may be due to multiple dependencies of slf4j , so i excluded slf4j from all dependencies, still i am getting this error.

I have following doubt , can you please clarify ..

 Since i want to use slf4j for logging , i added it in dependency too, but since i was getting exception might be due to multiple slf4j version dependency which i thought other dependency are downloading . Should i exclude it from other dependency or not???

Comment: Hi Sheltem , 
can you help me what should i do to remove this exception, since i am stuck on this exception badly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm assuming you are using Maven 3.x. So, add a `<dependencyManagement>` section to your POM in which you configure the actual version of slf4j (this would go in your parent POM so all modules use these overrides):

```
<properties>
  <slf4j.version>1.7.5</slf4j.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
   <dependencies>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
         <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
         <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
      </dependency>
      <!-- Since slf4j is a bridge, you need an implementation of it that would 
      redirect all calls to slf4j or JCL. Following is to perform logging using 
      the basic implementation, choose your preferred implementation 
      (it seems you were using logback). -->
      <dependency>
         <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
         <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
         <version>${slf4j.version}</version>
         <scope>runtime</scope>
      </dependency>
   </dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>
```

Then, in your modules' POM, use the dependencies in your main `<dependencies>` section as follows (I'd suggest to also remove the exclusions from the other dependencies, Maven should be able to pick the right versions since you are already overriding it):

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
     </dependency>
     <!-- Other dependencies -->
     ...
</dependencies>
```

Now perform a `mvn clean install` from the root of your project.